# bootstrap 5 rendering issue on mobile devices (parts of the layout freezing, clipping or hanging on the last layout)

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, html-rendering

it works fine on desktop but, this what happens on mobile

**what it looked like**

[image: what it looked like]
[image: what it looked like]

**what it should look like**

[image: what it should look like]
[image: what it should look like]

this feels like it lacks more description but i think the visuals is just fine

Comment: it seems to have something with `display:flex`, still not sure

Comment: it only glitches on chrome mobile (updated to latest version) on my vivoY91i (tried adblocker browser,Vivo browser and it works fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after fiddling around, it's not bootstrap's fault, it's chrome itself!
I uninstall all updates and it works fine, I noticed it glitched on StackOverflow too so I know that my website is fine